# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have method to add data to db on Aajax request

Here is code on back-end

```
   public ActionResult AddingInternalAppointment(string Start, string End, string Title, DateTime Date,int id)
    {

        using (var ctx = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {

            Appointment appointmentInt = new Appointment()
            {
                Start_appointment = Start,
                End_appointment = End,
                Title = Title,
                Type_of_appointment = "Internal",
                Date = Date
            };
            ctx.Appointments.Add(appointmentInt);
            ctx.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new {Result = "Success", Message = "Saved Successfully"});
        }
    }
```

And here is AJAX request on front - end:

```
function addAppointmentInternal() {
    var idofdoctor = moment($('#startAppointment').val()).toISOString();
    alert(idofdoctor);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: {
            Start: $('#startAppointment').val(),
            End: $('#endAppointment').val(),
            Title: $('#title').val(),
            Date: moment($('#startAppointment').val()).toISOString()
        },
        url: '@Url.Action("AddingInternalAppointment","Calendar")',
        success: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                $("#myModal2").modal();
            } else {
                alert('Error' + da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function(da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```

When I call this function it show me this error, but I have values in Date.

How I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Try changing parameter name Date to something else (alike appointmentDate), it seems like it is keyword, so you can't use it as a parameter. You need to change same in ajax call.

Comment: what is the value of `$('#startAppointment').val()` at the time of calling the ajax ?

Comment: Error not in this value @Wndrr

Comment: You were right, thank's@DSR

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, you can accept it, if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing parameter name `Date` to something else (like `appointmentDate`). You need to change same in ajax call.

Comment: This is nonsense. `Date` is not a reserved keyword. How on earth did this get up voted and accepted. And FYI, [here are the reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/)

Answer (score 1):

A few things.

Create a model for the Action

```
public class AppointmentOptions {
    public string Start { get; set;} 
    public string End { get; set;} 
    public string Title { get; set;} 
    public DateTime Date { get; set;} 
    public int Id { get; set;} 
}
```

Update the action accordingly

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddingInternalAppointment([FromBody]AppointmentOptions model) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        string Start = model.Start;
        string End = model.End;
        //...
    //...code removed for brevity
}
```

Next on the client update ajax call

```
function addAppointmentInternal() {
    var idofdoctor = moment($('#startAppointment').val()).toISOString();
    var model = {
            Start: $('#startAppointment').val(),
            End: $('#endAppointment').val(),
            Title: $('#title').val(),
            Date: moment($('#startAppointment').val()).toISOString()
        };
    alert(idofdoctor);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Post',
        dataType: 'Json',
        data: JSON.stringify(model), //<-- NOTE
        url: '@Url.Action("AddingInternalAppointment","Calendar")',
        success: function (da) {
            if (da.Result === "Success") {
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
                $("#myModal2").modal();
            } else {
                alert('Error' + da.Message);
            }
        },
        error: function(da) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
}
```